# Ignoring first few lines of top command with awk doesn't work

Tags: awk

I am trying to save output of `top` command in `csv` file. I want to ignore first six lines of `top` command that includes information e.g., %cpu, MiB Mem etc. I am using `awk` to achieve that as follow:

```
$ top | awk "NR<=5 {next;} {print}
```

The output of above command is correct as follows:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                 
75597 mustans+  20   0   21100   4292   3524 R  18.8   0.0   0:00.03 top                                                                     
1945 mustans+  20   0 5035316 296380  95244 S   6.2   1.8  35:58.70 gnome-shell
```

Above output is the desired output but after few seconds first six lines also appears as follows:

```
top - 12:24:40 up 2 days, 23:58,  1 user,  load average: 1.02, 0.83, 0.58
     17 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1                                                                 
%Cpu(s):  1.1 us,  1.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 95.1 id,  2.8 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  15906.9 total,   2265.8 free,   7633.8 used,   6007.3 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   7629.0 total,   7625.9 free,      3.1 used.   7260.9 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                 
    747 systemd+  20   0   24492  13784   9336 S   3.7   0.1   0:08.20 systemd-resolve                                                         
  37955 mustans+  20   0 7648180   2.0g  63944 S   3.7  12.7  94:16.16 java
```

How can I ensure on every `refresh` of `top` command, first few lines should be skipped with `awk`. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `ps` and its `-o` option to get desired columns.

Comment: Better option is to use `ps -o ...`.
If you want to continue with `top`, use `-n 1` option to stop iteration after first print.
After that you will consider some output troubles with ANSI sequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved through `ps` command to output in desired format i.e., remove initial few lines and then print the command alongwith cpu %.

```
ps -eo cmd,%cpu -p$(pidof process1),$(pidof process2) | awk "NR==1 {next;} {print $1}
```

Answer (score 0):

The pipe output from top doesn't start over every time it refreshes, you end up with a long list of lines being sent to awk.  You are only discarding the first 5 lines.

You could make it restart and get what you want by using watch to execute it yourself every second eg `watch -n 1 'top -n 1 | awk "NR<=5 {next;} {print}"'`

This may not be the best way to do what you're trying to do though.... you may want to look at using something like `ps` to get the information you want and not have to use awk.